# How to send data via Javascript - Jquery

Tags: jquery

How to send data via Javascript - Jquery

Comment: send data where ? what kind of data ?

Comment: from where to where, what is your current code, what is your problem, what have you already tried (I would vote that down but its not even worth wasting my points ....)

Comment: Hannes, your 1888 reputation cannot compete with Gani's 8... he/she is a member of SO for only 2 days now... we're a community to offer helping hand, not to undermine other's feelings, please consider that when posting comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url: url_page, 
  data: ({id: 1, data: 1212}),
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to send some data to a server side script your could use AJAX. jQuery has great support through [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getjson/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/script',
    data: { key1: 'value 1', key2: 'value 2' },
    success: function(result) {
        alert('data successfully sent');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

$.post() or $.send() www.jquery.com